# get rid of numbers in json response (LARAVEL 8)

Tags: json, laravel, api, response

my function in a controller is here below

```
public function getStudentsinGrade($grade, $school_id){
       $students =  Student::where('school_id', $school_id)->get();
           $this -> grade = $grade;
       $gradeStudent= $students->filter(function($value,$key){
            return $value->grade == $this->grade;
       });
       if(count($gradeStudent) > 0){
        return  response()->json($gradeStudent);
       }
       else{
        return  response('No Registered Student');
       }
    }
```

the response I am getting is here below

```
*{
    "2": <---this number here is the problem and it appeared when get API response
{
        "id": 14,
        "student_name": "Polly Grain",
        "gender": "Female",
        "stream_id": 1,
        "school_id": 1,
        "final_year_id": 2,
        "grade": "Form Four"
    },
    "3": {
        "id": 15,
        "student_name": "Polly Grain",
        "gender": "Male",
        "stream_id": 3,
        "school_id": 1,
        "final_year_id": 2,
        "grade": "Form Four"}
}*
```

and the response I want to get is the one below

> [
> {
> "id": 1,
> "student_name": "sae sddat",
> "gender": "male",
> "stream_id": 2,
> "school_id": 10,
> "final_year_id": 12,
> "grade": "Form One"
> },
> {
> "id": 1,
> "student_name": "sae sddat",
> "gender": "male",
> "stream_id": 2,
> "school_id": 10,
> "final_year_id": 12,
> "grade": "Form One"
> },
> {
> "id": 1,
> "student_name": "sae sddat",
> "gender": "male",
> "stream_id": 2,
> "school_id": 10,
> "final_year_id": 12,
> "grade": "Form One"
> }
> ]

Comment: This is definitely an issue caused by your collection filter

Comment: Why are you filtering on the collection instead of the eloquent query directly?

Comment: the parameter I am filtering is not direct  from the database but it the parameter when display the student by calculations, maybe you can help me from there on how to use eloquent in that situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, first convert your collection  to an array, then use the `array_values()` function to get rid of those annoying array keys that are bothering you. After that, convert back to a collection and pass it as a json response.
**IN CODE:**

```
public function getStudentsinGrade($grade, $school_id){
       $students =  Student::where('school_id', $school_id)->get();
           $this -> grade = $grade;
       $gradeStudent= $students->filter(function($value,$key){
            return $value->grade == $this->grade;
       });
       if(count($gradeStudent) > 0){
       $gradeStudent = collect(array_values($gradeStudent->toArray()));
      
        return  response()->json($gradeStudent);
       }
       else{
        return  response('No Registered Student');
       }
    }
```

Now this will give you the desired result like this:

```
{
        "id": 14,
        "student_name": "Polly Grain",
        "gender": "Female",
        "stream_id": 1,
        "school_id": 1,
        "final_year_id": 2,
        "grade": "Form Four"
    },
{
        "id": 15,
        "student_name": "Polly Grain",
        "gender": "Male",
        "stream_id": 3,
        "school_id": 1,
        "final_year_id": 2,
        "grade": "Form Four"}
}
```

Comment: thanks for the view but this is not array of objects I was trying to get

Comment: and I am getting this error message 

    "message": "Call to a member function collect() on array",

Comment: did you use ```->collect()``` ?

Comment: thanks @Innovin this answered my issue and I resolved the error

Answer (score 1):

Why not add additional where clause to your query

```
public function getStudentsinGrade($grade, $school_id){
       $students =  Student::where('school_id', $school_id)
        ->where('grade', $grade)
        ->get();
           
       if($students->count() > 0){
        return  response()->json($gradeStudent);
       }
       else{
        return  response('No Registered Student');
       }
    }
```

Comment: this can't solve the problem